# How to get element name in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a element:

```
private elementRef: ElementRef;
```

I have tried to get element name using this:

```
console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.name);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this...

Set value:
`this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute("name", "myName");`

or

Get value:
`this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute("name");`